# .NET MAUI Integration Testing - FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Maui.Essentials

Tags: entity-framework-core, moq, maui

I'm attempting to integration test a .NET MAUI application utilizing entity framework core.
When the code gets to the line 'this.Database.EnsureCreated()', it gives a file not found exception.

The first thought was trying to reference Microsoft.Maui.Essentials, though when I search for it in NuGet, all I can find is Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.___ which doesn't seem compatible with my project.

If I try to install it, I get the error 'The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.any 6.0.547 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project'

How can I resolve this error?

The full length exception is:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Maui.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Integration test code:

```
...
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Test_Database")
                .Options;
            var mockDataContext = new Mock<DataContext>(options);
            mockDataContextCreator
                .Setup(x => x.CreateDbContext())
                .Returns(new DataContext(options));
...
```

DataContext.cs

```
public class DataContext : DbContext

...

public DataContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
            SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();

            if (!this.Database.EnsureCreated())
            {
                this.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
```

The Database property is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade' and is defined in the base class 'DbContext'.

Integration Test CSPROJ File:

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies" Version="6.0.547" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Extensions" Version="6.0.547" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

Comment: Have you already tried adding the `Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies` nuget instead? You're saying that `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref` is not compatible with your project, but how do you know that? Please show relevant parts of your project files and also please don't post exceptions as images, always use text. That makes it easier to copy and search.

Comment: Where is the `Database` property/instance defined? Upon further looking at your code, I believe that your hard dependency is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is surprisingly easy. Add **UseMauiEssentials** to your test project file. Alternatively you can utilize **UseMaui**, the difference is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74920840/what-is-the-difference-between-usemauiessentials-and-usemaui-in-the-android).

At least this worked for me out-of-the-box within almost the same setup (xUnit). Took me few hours to find this after number of more complicated but not robust enough attempts.

One of my failing attempts was to add "Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies" NuGet package. I can see it in your original post. With the fix suggested this NuGet package is not needed.

```xml
<PropertyGroup> 
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>  
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>  
    <UseMauiEssentials>true</UseMauiEssentials>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: MAUI on DotNet7 here. Before adding `UseMauiEssentials`, while debugging tests, I was getting an unhandled exception as per OP. After adding `UserMauiEssentials`, I get: _Unexpected error occurred. Check the Output pane for information_. The Output pane shows no error if "Build" is selected, it even says _Build succeeded_. Instead, selecting "Debug" shows `Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in WindowsAPITests.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Maui.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified`.