# What is the difference between <UseMauiEssentials> and <UseMaui> in the Android/iOS csproj file? Should I use both in my csproj files?

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I want to use .NET MAUI in my existing Android and iOS projects but I'm not sure if I need to add UseMauiEssentials and UseMaui or only one of them to my existing csproj files. Currently I use Xamarin.Essentials and some other Xamarin NuGet packages in my Android and iOS projects.

My Android csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-android</TargetFramework>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>23</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.AndroidprojectwithXamarin</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task" Version="3.8.1.303" />
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Framework.Android" Version="3.8.1.303" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="RestoreDotnetTools" BeforeTargets="Restore">
    <Message Text="Restoring dotnet tools" Importance="High" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

My iOS csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-ios</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>15.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task" Version="3.8.1.303" />
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Framework.iOS" Version="3.8.1.303" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="RestoreDotnetTools" BeforeTargets="Restore">
    <Message Text="Restoring dotnet tools" Importance="High" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

What is the difference between UseMauiEssentials and UseMaui in the Android/iOS csproj files? Should I use both in my csproj files?
Is it necessary to remove the Xamarin.Essentials NuGet package from my projects? Is it necessary to add another .NET MAUI NuGet package if I want to use .NET MAUI? Or should I leave the Xamarin.Essentials NuGet package installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've already found, Xamarin.Essentials was a separate project. Essentials was basically an abstraction layer for all kinds of APIs that are available across the different platforms (iOS, Android, Windows) but don't necessarily have any UI.

Since Xamarin.Forms was a UI framework, all of Essentials was not included in Forms. In fact, you can use Xamarin.Essentials with a traditional Xamarin application if you want, there is no dependency on Forms.

With the introduction of .NET MAUI, Essentials as a separate concept kind of went away. Essentials is now an integrated part of .NET MAUI and it's just APIs that are available for you to use.

However, those APIs still have no dependency on .NET MAUI and you should be able to use Essentials without using .NET MAUI. And that is where we get to the answer of this question: use `UseMauiEssentials` if you just want to use the APIs formerly known as Essentials, or, if you're going to use all of .NET MAUI anyway, just include `UseMaui` that will also bring in Essentials automatically.

Comment: Does that work with *"existing Android and iOS projects"*? The APIs should work, but the UI framework won't, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand what you mean. If you update your existing project to .NET 6 (or up) and add `<UseMauiEssentials>true</UseMauiEssentials>` then you will get access to APIs like `SecureStorage`, `Preferences`, etc. anything that was originally in Essentials. You will _not_ get access to anything in .NET MAUI like a `Button` or a `Label`. You will need to create the UI in the platform native way.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I meant.

Comment: What should I do if there are more Xamarin NuGet packages installed in one Android/iOS project and not just Xamarin.Essentials? For example, I have an Android project where I use the NuGet packages Xamarin.Essentials, Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging, Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base. I don't use default buttons or labels, I use my own sprites to create buttons and labels in my projects. I'm not sure if I should use <UseMauiEssentials> or <UseMaui> in this project. What should be better?

Comment: Are all the APIs that were originally in different NuGet packages(like for example: Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging, Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base) now in .NET MAUI or are only the APIs from Xamarin.Essentials in .NET MAUI? I don't know if I need to have any Xamarin NuGet packages installed if I already use UseMauiEssentials in my csproj file.

Comment: Definitely not all of those are now part of .NET MAUI. Essentials is the only one that was taken in, the rest is still separate libraries. You will need to check if there is a version available that works with (at least) .NET 6.